# How set Theme in main activity api 7?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-manifest

I offer my users a light and dark option for theming.

The error in the Log:

> Caused by: `java.lang.IllegalStateException`: You must use `Theme.Sherlock`, `Theme.Sherlock.Light`, `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`, or a derivative.

The error occurs in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in the MainActivity.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {.....public static int globalTheme;
Context context;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    context = getApplicationContext();
    mySharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("proxy", false);
    editor.commit();

    if (mySharedPreferences.getString(Preferences.PREF_THEME, "1").trim().equals("1"))
        globalTheme = R.style.Sherlock___Theme;
    else
        globalTheme = R.style.Sherlock___Theme_Light;
    setTheme(globalTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I did not add something in the manifest, because the themes should be changed dynamically
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
   />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="com.belasheuski.activities.MyApplication"
     >
    <activity
        android:name="com.belasheuski.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/name_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This error occurs on API 7. On API 15 all works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm setting this in this way ...

```
 setTheme(isLightTheme ? R.style.MyApp_Light : R.style.MyApp);
```

where the style definition are looking like ...

```
 <style name="MyApp.Light" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.ForceOverflow">
     <item name="overlayedActionBarBackground">@color/overlayedActionBarLight</item>

     ...
 </style>

 <style name="MyApp" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow">
     <item name="overlayedActionBarBackground">@color/overlayedActionBarDark</item>

     ...
 </style>
```

That works pretty fine. So I think you took the wrong style definition from ABS.

Cheers!

Comment: great answer! thank you very much:) I wrote `  <style name="MyApp.Light" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    
 </style>

 <style name="MyApp" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">

</style>` I do not understand what is "ForceOverflow" and ` <item name="overlayedActionBarBackground">@color/overlayedActionBarDark</item>

     ...` but it work and it is good) good site

Comment: ForceOverflow is needed if your ActionBar can only show two Items (e.g. on a small device) but you know you are going to have four items. Usually two of them are just cut, however, using ForceOverflow you get this icon for further menu icons.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what is wrong, your theme must be "Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative."

This is occuring on API 7 but not on API 15 because API 15 has native ActionBar support, so that is used, while this is not the case on API 7, and hence the need for the theming.

Answer (score 0):

Going from the error:

> You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative."

It seems that your custom `style` does not inherit from a `Sherlock` theme. Check the `styles.xml` file in your `values` folder and ensure they inherit from one of those.